# Fantasy book of girl with magical stones used for flying, healing, etc

Tags: story-identification, books

Maybe adult or could be teen story of girl being groomed for possible induction into witches’ circle that uses magical stones for healing, flying, etc. Slaves are made of abducted villagers around the lake area. The lake has monsters that attack and eat people.

Comment: This is quite sparse can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in some more details? For example, when did you read this? Any specific memorable plot points?

Comment: Are all of the magic users female in this novel?  Does the book stand alone or is it part of a series?  Possible answer but need more information...

Answer (score 2):

[*Child of a Mad God*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/35018912) is the title. It's part of the '*Coven*' series by R.A. Salvatore

> When Aoleyn loses her parents, she is left to fend for herself among a tribe of vicious barbarians. Bound by rigid traditions, she dreams of escaping to the world beyond her mountain home.
>
> The only hope for achieving the kind of freedom she searches for is to learn how to wield the mysterious power used by the tribe’s coven known as the Song of Usgar. Thankfully, Aoleyn may be the strongest witch to have ever lived, but magic comes at price. Not only has her abilities caught the eye of the brutish warlord that leads the tribe, but the demon of the mountain hunts all who wield the Coven’s power, and Aoleyn’s talent has made her a beacon in the night.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the book the OP was looking for, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't. It'd help other users decide how likely this answer is to be correct or not.